# Float64 typed constant in go, loses precision

Tags: go, floating-point, integer

Consider the following code written in go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    const pi float64 = 22 / 7
    fmt.Println("pi value", pi)
}
```

here the value of `pi` is `3`. The question is why is the value losing precision even though it is of type `float64`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NeverMind, I got the answer.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    const pi float64 = 22.0 / 7.0
    fmt.Println("pi value", pi)
}
```

Output  `3.142857142857143`. it seems types depend if type integer are be divided, it will return a integer regardless if the receiving var is type float64. so get a float value, devision has you occur between float values.

Comment: Not exactly what you are doing but related, for some popular constants, you can also use `math` package constant values. So say for pi, you can just use `math.Pi` and you don't have to compute the value. http://golang.org/pkg/math/

Comment: @CuriousMind The reason for this conversion is that for constant values automatic type conversion is applied (this only happens with constant values). Integer division of `22/7` is done and the result is converted to `float64`.

Comment: See [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants#TOC_8.). In particular, you can have a very high precision constant if you leave it untyped, e.g. `const b = 22.0 / 7`; this can make a difference if you do further constant math before assignment.